# Error E0146 : Too many initializer values C++

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, c++17

I have a school project and I have to use the AM in the Student.h as a char*.The AM have to have numbers in it. I can't understand why what I am doing is not working.
Student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Student dlg;
    dlg.AM[10]={2,1,3,9,0,2,6,6};
    
}
```

Student.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    char *AM[20];
    string Name;
    unsigned int Semester = 1;
};
```

Comment: `char*` is neither "array", nor "string", so assigning `{2,1,3,9,0,2,6,6}` to the 11th element o fthe `dlg.AM` array (denoted by `dlg.AM[10]`) will not work in neither C nor C++. If you want `AM` to be an array of integers, use `std::vector<int> AM;` instead.

Comment: @yeputons could you please give me an example of how to use the "std::vector<int> AM;" ?

Comment: What is AM supposed to represent?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod its a number that every university student get's.

Comment: @KostasG that's very odd.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I made a change in the  (memcpy(new char[16], strInt.c_str(), strInt.size())) The only change I did was the "new char[16]" to make it "new char[1]" and those question marks almost left, but there is still this "2²²²β☻
1²²²
3²²²    ^╗|KνH
9²²²β☻
0²²²
2²²²    ^╗|KνH
6²²²β☻
6²²²β☻"

Comment: @KostasG you changed it to a one byte string, which is not long enough to hold a string representation of a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need your student number to be a char string, then you need to convert your ints to char* before assigning them to the array.

```
int main()
{
    Student dlg;
    int j = 0;
    for (auto i : {2,1,3,9,0,2,6,6})
    {
        auto strInt { std::to_string(i) }; // create a C++ string containing a int
        // next copy the internal memory of the C++ string to a read-writable memory buffer
        // and assign a pointer to that buffer casted to a char* to the appropriate slot in the array
        dlg.AM[j++] = static_cast<char*> (std::memcpy (new char[16], strInt.c_str(), strInt.size()));
    }
    // test
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        cout << dlg.AM[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Are you sure the student number should be a char* ?

Comment: Just seen your answer, I am sure that the student number has to be a char * . Also I got the code you send me but the console give me this "2═══════════════²²²² 1═══════════════²²²²▌▌▌▌FEV}▌☻ 3═══════════════²²²² 9═══════════════²²²² 0═══════════════²²²² 2═══════════════²²²² 6═══════════════²²²²▌▌▌▌♣E↨}▌☼ 6═══════════════²²²²"

Comment: @KostasG The code demo is here:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b24b0cd28a232665

Comment: it does not work at all. In what version of the language did you write this?

Comment: @KostasG It is C++17. Did you try the demo?

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work properly